# What are Game Maker drawbacks?

Tags: game-maker

I actually make games only programming (SFML atm), but I was taking a look at game maker features and it looks very powerful.

What are Game Maker drawbacks? any reason why I shouldn't move into it?

It works for little games, but still it work fine with bigger projects? is it internally fast?

Thanks